# Permission Denial - requires android.permission.CALL_PHONE which is granted

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am initiating call using `Notification`'s action:

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:+48123456"));
PendingIntent pCallIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, callIntent, 0);

Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(context)
        .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_call, "Call", pCallIntent)
        .build();

notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

After triggering `Call` button I get following `SecurityException`:

```
05-06 20:00:09.275    3426-6293/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ Unable to send startActivity intent
    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL dat=tel:xxxxxxxxxxxx flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.phone/.OutgoingCallBroadcaster bnds=[128,231][423,327] } from null (pid=-1, uid=10142) requires android.permission.CALL_PHONE
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1191)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:746)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityInPackage(ActivityManagerService.java:3391)
            at com.android.server.am.PendingIntentRecord.sendInner(PendingIntentRecord.java:252)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityIntentSender(ActivityManagerService.java:3272)
            at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:237)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2146)
            at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

I have set proper permissions in `AndroidManifest`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

What should I do to fix it ?

Comment: What device is that? (Can the device even make phone calls?)

Comment: @Ahmad Sure it can. It's SGS i9305.

Comment: Try using that same `Intent` somewhere directly in your app, versus in a `PendingIntent` for the `Notification`. If it fails there too, then your manifest may be malformed, such as having that `<uses-permission>` element in the wrong spot. If the `Intent` works, then the issue is that this permission is not propagating with the `PendingIntent` to the OS process that runs your `PendingIntent`.

Comment: @CommonsWare If I trigger notification from `Activity` it works. It looks I have a bad design pattern in my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `PendingIntent` is supposed to include the "security context" in which it was created, so I am a bit surprised that this isn't working, though I have certainly never tried to call a phone number from a `Notification`.

Your likely options are:

- Switch to `DIAL_PHONE`, as that does not need a permission.
- Have your `PendingIntent` route to a `BroadcastReceiver` of yours, which turns around and calls the phone number. Make sure that this is a non-exported `BroadcastReceiver` (i.e., no `<intent-filter>`), so other apps do not send you the broadcast, causing you to call the number at possibly inopportune moments.